# How to use characteristic polynomial to find eigenvalue and determine diagonalization of matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If the matrix, $$A = \begin{pmatrix}-3&0&0 \\\ -4&-7&8\\-4&-4&5 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> - Find the characteristic polynomial of A and, hence, find all the eigenvalues of A.
> - Parametrizing (as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3)$ the eigenspace of A that corresponds to the eigenvalue $\lambda = -3$. Is it possible to diagonalize A?

So far I have taken the determinant of $(A-\lambda I)$ and got the characteristic polynomial $-\lambda^{2} -5\lambda^{2} -3\lambda +9$. Then calculated the eigenvalues to be $\lambda = 1, -3$. After this, I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: There’s an easier way for this matrix. Hint: At least two eigenvalues are easily found by inspection, and you can always get the last one “for free” by considering the trace of the matrix.

Comment: @Bernard I am not familiar with the trace of the matrix, how does that work?

Comment: The trace of a square matrix is the sum of its diagonal coefficients. It happens that it is also the sum of its eigenvalues (counted with multiplicity). You can see more details on  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not expand the determinant of $A-\lambda I$, but try to factor it:
\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}
-3-\lambda &&0 \\ -4&-7-\lambda &8 \\ -4&-4&5-\lambda\end{vmatrix}&=\begin{vmatrix}
-3-\lambda &&0\\-4&-7-\lambda &8 \\ 0&3+\lambda&-3-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=(3+\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}
-3-\lambda &&0\\-4&-7-\lambda &8 \\ 0&1&-1\end{vmatrix}\\[1ex]
&=(3+\lambda)\Bigl[(-3-\lambda)(\lambda+7-8)\Bigr]=-(\lambda+3)^2(\lambda-1)
\end{align}

Second, to determine if the matrix is diagonalisable, you have to check whether the *geometric multiplicity* is equal to the *algebraic multiplicity* of each of the eigenvalues.

For $1$, which is a *simple* eigenvalue, there is no problem. For the double eigenvalue $-3$, this means you have to check whether the corresponding eigenspace $\ker(A+3I)$ has dimension $2$.